# Is it possible in Grails to join mongo and mysql domains?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have one domain using MySQL db, other domain uses MongoDB. Can I join them?

For example:

Appeal (mongo domain)

```
class Appeal {

    static mapWith = "mongo"

    Organization organization <=== MySQL domain
    ...
}
```

Organization (MySQL domain)

```
class Organization {
    ... 
    static hasMany = [ appeals : Appeal ]; <==join to mongo domain
}
```

Exception is :

```
Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
to bean '$primaryTransactionManager' while setting constructor
argument with key [0]; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve
reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property
'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:
Association references unmapped class: lc.itgroup.education.dao.Appeal
    Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
to bean '$primaryTransactionManager' while setting constructor
argument with key [0]; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve
reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property
'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:
Association references unmapped class: lc.itgroup.education.dao.Appeal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can approximate it. You would have the same problem joining two tables in two different relational databases - each gets its own `SessionFactory` and there's no support in Hibernate or GORM to join across databases or datastores.

To approximate it, store the primary key of the other table/document and use transient methods to retrieve the instance for you. This is basically what Hibernate does for you - it stores the foreign key value and auto-loads the instance on demand.

```
class Appeal {

    static mapWith = "mongo"

    void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        organizationId = organization.id
    }
    Organization getOrganization() {
        organizationId ? Organization.get(organizationId) : null
    }
    static transients = ['organization']

    Long organizationId
    ...
}
```

Using this approach, your code will be very similar to what it would look like if both tables were in the same database. When you access the `Organization` it will be retrieved from the database using the id that was previously persisted.

It's important that the `organization` property be transient since having a matched get/set pair like this would be considered a persistent property and as you've seen, this will fail. Only the id should be persisted.